# Display payment status of users in Laravel with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to display user payment status month wise. I am trying but I am not getting any idea to achieve this.

I have two table:

1. User table( ID, User name, updated at, created at)
2. Payment table (ID, user_id, payment status, payment)

I am trying to achieve below scenario using query:

```
Select * from users where updated_at=**selectmonth**
```

But I am not getting result which I want.

Suppose admin select month **August 2019** then display all users with its payment status and date of august month like:

| **Name** | **Payment Status** | **Payment Date**

---

**|** ABC    **|**      Done          **|** 01-08-2019

**|**   XYZ    **|**      Not Done      **|** 02-08-2019

If admin select **April 2019** from the dropdown then display users details of April month same like above.

Added static data in table. I want to make something like that.

[image]

Kindly suggest how can I display users record?

Comment: Is there a specific part that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Can you give more information?? Eg Post the DB structure for your two tables, and post the SQL statements you've attempted in order to get better quality of help. We aren't psychic

Comment: you should post your progress, not only your db structure,
thats how stackoverflow works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this: below is the table structure in png. the payment status has default value 0. when record enters into the table it changes to 1. here 0 stands for not done. 1 stands for done. [image]

in your controller, do this:

```
public function showPaymentDetails(Request $request)
    {
        $dateInput=$request->input(dateselect);

        $data['users']=DB::table('user_table')
        ->leftjoin('payment_table','user_table.idusertable','=','payment_table.user_table_idusertable')
        ->orderby('user_table.idusertable','desc')
        ->where('payment_table.paymentDate','=',$dateInput)
        ->get();
        return view('usersform',$data);
    }
```

then in your blade, you can display the record. you can do some logic on your blade to show done/not done:

```
<div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
                                          <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
                                            <thead>
                                              <tr bgcolor="#c7c7c7">
                                                <th>S/N</th>
                                                <th>UserName</th>
                                                <th>Phone</th>
                                                <th>Location</th>
                                                <th>Email</th>
                                                <th>PaymentDate</th>
                                                <th>Payment Status</th>

                                              </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                            <tbody>

                                              @php
                                              $i=1;
                                              @endphp
                                                @foreach($users as $list)

                                                   <tr>
                                                   <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>

                                                   <td>{{ $list->fullname}}</td>
                                                   <td>{{ $list->phone}}</td>
                                                   <td>{{ $list->location}}</td>
                                                   <td>{{ $list->email}}</td>
                                                   <td>{{ $list->paymentDate}}</td>
                                                   <td> @if($list->paymentDate==0){{ 'Not Done' }} @elsif($list->paymentStatus==1) {{ 'Done' }} @endif</td>
                                                   </tr>
                                               @endforeach
                                                </tbody>

                                          </table>
                                           <hr />


                                        </div>
```

//your route

```
Route::Post('/display-payment-details',   'YourController@showPaymentDetails');
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am trying your solution. I will let you know once it successfully done.

Comment: also know that i created relationships for the 2 tables for easier querying

Answer (score 0):

Providing that the users and the payments are connected with a foreign key in the db (see [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) about relationships) you can achieve this in several ways. I will focus on the code which retrieves the results, because we have no detail about the exact scenario:

**Example 1**
If you are in a user-centric context, given a `payments` one-to-many relationship:

```
// You can perform this or more specific queries
User::with( 'payments' )->get();
// this will return all the users, with an additional property `payments` which is a collection of the user payments
```

In a more "scoped" way:

```
$date = '2019-02-01'; // This is a basic example
User::with( 'payments', function( $query ) use ($date) {
    return $query->where( [ ['date', '<', Carbon::createDateFromString($date)->addMonths(1)], ['date', '>', Carbon::createDateFromString($date)->subMonths(1)] ] );
} )->get();
```

**Example 2**
If you are in a payment-centric context, given a `user` relationship which is defined by Laravel's `belongTo` (see doc linked above):

```
$payments = Payment::with( 'user' )->where( [ ['date', '<', Carbon::createDateFromString($date)->addMonths(1)], ['date', '>', Carbon::createDateFromString($date)->subMonths(1)] ] )->get();
// this gets the payment you are looking for.

foreach($payments as $payment) {
    $user = $payment->user;
}
```

You can also get related models via `lazy-loading` (again see the documentation above), or you can create a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes)